# How to implement wildcard subdomain in hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I need to implement wildcard subdomain on Hapi.js server. I have main domain let's assume. example.com Now I need to implement *.example.com which I have already set DNS to point to the hapi.js server. 
So If I visit client1.example.com I will need to get the client1 value and check it in mongodb tables and do some actions based on it.

I have tried to use server.ext

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
  console.log(request.info);
  return reply.continue();
});
```

but this gives me host value of localhost:8080

```
{ received: 1420285577874,
  responded: 0,
  remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',
  remotePort: 58001,
  referrer: '',
  host: 'localhost:8080',
  acceptEncoding: 'gzip',
  hostname: 'localhost' }
```

I guess this is because Hapi.js is behind proxy. Is there any way I can easily get the subdomain value. Also Is there any better alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: All proxy allows to pass original host to app. Usually in header `x-original-host` or something like that

Comment: OK i was able to get proper host name by adding ProxyPreserveHost On in apache virtual host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Above question I was able to use ProxyPreserveHost On in apache virtual host to preserve host in info object.